Cannot Install Tensorflow in Anaconda Prompt
when I try to install tensorflow it gives me the message below. My OS is windows 11. Please help me. Thank you.
(py3-TF2.0) C:\Windows\System32>conda install tensorflow
Channels:

defaults

Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: / warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE

failed



LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:

  - nothing provides bleach 1.5.0 needed by tensorboard-1.7.0-py35he025d50_1



Could not solve for environment specs

The following packages are incompatible

├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires

│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;

└─ tensorflow is not installable because there are no viable options

   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.9.0] would require

   │  └─ python 3.5.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;

   ├─ tensorflow [1.10.0|1.11.0|...|2.1.0] would require

   │  └─ python 3.6.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;

   ├─ tensorflow [1.13.1|1.14.0|...|2.9.1] would require

   │  └─ python 3.7.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;

   ├─ tensorflow [1.7.0|1.7.1|1.8.0] would require

   │  └─ tensorboard [>=1.7.0,<1.8.0 |>=1.8.0,<1.9.0 ], which requires

   │     └─ bleach 1.5.0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);

   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require

   │  └─ python 3.10.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;

   ├─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.3.0|...|2.9.1] would require

   │  └─ python 3.8.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;

   └─ tensorflow [2.10.0|2.5.0|2.6.0|2.8.2|2.9.1] would require

      └─ python 3.9.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

I was simply trying instructions from this online video and it did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

t seems like you're encountering dependency conflicts while trying to install TensorFlow via Conda.Sometimes, updating Conda to the latest version can help resolve dependency conflicts. Instead of using Conda, you can try installing TensorFlow using pip, which may have a different set of dependencies resolved:**pip install tensorflow
**.
